# How do I use Tableau to populate the count of each dimension over a time period?

Tags: tableau-api

**How do I populate the number of purchases and sales per day in tableau?**

[Here is my Sample Data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PC9Q.png)

In my first attempt, sales numbers are not counted to the exact date.
In my second attempt, I tried to tabulate by dropping sales date into the rows. However, it returned two figures - purchases and sales.
I have also tried Calculated Field but Tableau is unable to do a "for loop" like python.

[First attempt:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjG4F.png)
[After dropping Sales Date into the Rows. This is what I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLE1t.png)

Is there any way to populate it like this? Please help, I am still new to tableau. Special thanks to Fabio Fantoni for the first solution!

[Desired Format:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuj08.png)

I have another sample data (refer to sample data 2) which I would like to populate in the desired format (refer to desired format 2). In Sample Data 2, the purchase date "15/12/2020" is not reflected in sold dates.

My apologies but I may require some guidance as I am still new to tableau. Thank you in advance.

[Sample Data 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF71f.png)
[Desired Format 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmVF.png)

Comment: Try counting the number of purchase days. If the purchase date is null wrap it with ZN (a function meant to replace NULL values with zero) - ZN(COUNT(DATETRUNC('day', [Purchase Date])))

Comment: Thank you bob. If my data set consist of various months and years. By using datetrunc day, I think it may not work

Comment: It does work. Review https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm

Answer (score 0):

Based on this sample:

[image]

In order to bypass your double count for two different date columns, you may want to cross join your original data with a copy of it on original.Purchase = support.Sold, like this:

[image]

Doing so, you just have to create two calculated fields:

count Purchase:

```
count([Purchase Date])
```

count Sold:

```
Count([Purchase Date (Foglio11)])
```

The only thing you have to pay attention to is that in the second calculus you have to count Purchase date due to your "inverted" cross join.

You should get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance. Pardon me but I’m new to tableau. Does this have any implications on the type of data I have? 

Must I have common set of dates in both purchase and sold dates? For example - if I no longer have 15/12/2020 in the dates would it still be able to count the number of sales for the day?

Comment: I tried, and it wouldn't count 15/12/2020. Is there any resolution to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you may want to choose the proper join type in the data source pane: inner, left, right, full outer... that being said, does the output of the answer meet your needs?

Comment: Yes the output has met my needs. However, when i tried to tweak the data (purchase date to not contain sales date), it does not produce the desired output.

Comment: This method requires that you "select" one date as your primary column serving as a sort  of reference for your output.

You can try, along with full outer join, adding another calculated field ifnull(purchase_date, sold_date) and use that in your chart instead of Purchase Date.

Anyway, please accept the answer if your need has been satisfied or edit your original post adding more context for your additional needs.

Comment: Apologies, I have added more context for my additional needs. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.